# ShowToastEvent not working in LWC in Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm calling an LWC from a flow. A parent lwc calls a child lwc. The child dispatches a custom event which calls a method on the parent that attempts to dispatch a showtoastevent.

child:

```
handleError(errorMessage) {

    console.log('Limit Reached');

    const limitEvent = new CustomEvent('limitreached', {
       detail: errorMessage
    });

    this.dispatchEvent(limitEvent);
}
```

parent:

```
handleNotification(event) {
    console.log('**********IN PARENT***********');
    console.log('DETAIL---'+event.detail);
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent ({
        title: 'Warning',
        message: event.detail,
        mode: 'pester',
        varant: 'error'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

I can see from the console that the parent method is called but nothing displays on the page.

Here it says that an embedded lwc in a vf page doesn't work either. Is this also true for an embedded lwc in a flow?
[ShowToastEvent notification is not displayed in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267571/showtoastevent-notification-is-not-displayed-in-lwc)

Comment: you wrote `varant`, try to rename it to `variant`

Comment: Good catch but that didn't fix the issue

Comment: Have you found the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. LWC in a flow, error when I try to dispatch a toast.

Comment: https://unofficialsf.com/show-toast-flow-action/

Answer (score 5):

You can show `ShowToastEvent` from embedded `LWC` in a flow.
There is no limits for it here : [lightning-platform-show-toast-event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation),

About `ShowToastEvent` not working in **Visualforce Pages**,
We use our **LWC** in a **Visualforce Page** using **Lightning Out**.
And `ShowToastEvent` doesn't work in Lightning Out (*Standalone Lightning App*, see targets for **Platform Show Toast Event**)

If there was something,
It would be included here : [Runtime Considerations for Flow Screen Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_runtime_considerations).

To check your case I created a simple **Screen Flow** and added one LWC to it.
Then I created a simple **Action** button from which I call this **Flow**
[image]

The flow **LWC** element :

[image]

The **LWC** JS code :

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
 
export default class TestFlowScreen extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        try {
            let eventDetail = 'TestFlowScreen';
            console.log('connectedCallback');
            console.log('DETAIL---' + eventDetail );
            const evt = new ShowToastEvent ({
                title: 'Warning',
                message: eventDetail,
                mode: 'pester',
                variant: 'error'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

And when I press the button, I see the **Event**.

[image]

**SO :**

Please ensure that you imported the `ShowToastEvent` as expected :

```js
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
```

- Double check if `event.detail` can be shown in `ShowToastEvent.message`.
- `variant` not `varant` !!!
- put your code from `handleNotification()` method in `try{}catch(error){}` block to see any errors happen.

*Please say if any of it fixed your issue.*

Comment: Hi, I used your example but it only works if the screen flow is called from a record page, or quick action... when I tried to call from a list view action (using the flow URL) didnt not work. BTW thank for you answer.  Still looking for a alternatives. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. As per documentation, platformShowToastEvent need to be imported in parent component js.

```javascript
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
```

Kindly check if import statement is there.
Documentation Link for your reference-> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation